# How to solve error "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 907DD86E" using PostgreSQL with EclipseLink JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-7

I'm trying to deploy my webapp on Heroku and I'm using Heroku PostgreSQL database and I encountered the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.10.v20211216-fe64cd39c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 907DD86E
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at DAO.ClientDAO.<init>(ClientDAO.java:17)
    at controllers.authServlet.doPost(authServlet.java:49)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:694)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.10.v20211216-fe64cd39c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 907DD86E
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.errorDecryptingPassword(ValidationException.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateLogins(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2481)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:752)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 907DD86E
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:963)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:123)
    ... 33 more
```

It looks like an issue (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/885) with EclipseLink trying to decrypt the database password. Unfortunately, I can't change it, I tried to pass in the datasource as a parameter instead similar to http://onpersistence.blogspot.com/2008/04/eclipselink-and-datasources.html

```java
public class ClientDAO implements Dao<Client> {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private BaseDataSource createDataSource() { 
          BaseDataSource dataSource = new BaseDataSource() {
             @Override public String getDescription() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return null; } };
          int[] portNumber = {5432}; 
          String[] serverName ={"SERVER_NAME"};  
          dataSource.setServerNames(serverName); dataSource.setPortNumbers(portNumber);
          dataSource.setDatabaseName("DB_NAME");
          dataSource.setUser("DB_USER"); 
          dataSource.setPassword("df9d43a7c7116b25f514f58a8dff9...");//some of the actual password
         return dataSource;
     }
    private EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() { 
          if (emf == null) {
                Map properties = new HashMap();
                properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE,createDataSource(
          ));
          emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("japa2", properties); 
          }
          return emf; 
    }
          
    
    private EntityManager entityManager;
        
    public ClientDAO() {
        super();
        emf = getEntityManagerFactory(); 
        entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
```

But still, when I run the app on the server the properties used in persistence.xml are the ones that have been used.

So is there any way to use the datasource that I pass instead of persistence.xml properties, or prevent EclipseLink from decrypting the password?

Comment: Do you see warnings when the Persistence unit is loading? (turn logging on if it isn't already: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging ). Logging would also show what it uses to connect and how, and might point to why it isn't doing what you want. What settings do you have in the persistence.xml?

Comment: After turnning the logger on this is the new exception description indicate :` at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.errorDecryptingPassword(ValidationException.java:896)`

Comment: there are only the database credentials in persistence.xml

Comment: Have you tried removing them? No point putting in the username/password in a static file if you aren't going to use them anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I solved the problem just by encrypting the password using this code http://www.javamonamour.org/2012/05/eclipse-jpa-errordecryptingpassword.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

You are using a 32 char password. Eclipselink thinks is encoded and tries to decode it unsuccsesfully, giving the exception you are receiving.

Change your password to a non 32 multiple length one.

The error is already reported to eclipse https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569945